# how to group data in plsql based on computation and plot chart from it?

Tags: sql, oracle, charts, plsql, oracle-apex

I have one table whose structure is as below.

```
task_id(pk)
task_title(varchar2)
task_due_date(date)
```

Now I want to plot a chart based on below condition.

1. No. of task which do not have due_date.
2. No. of tasks that are due under one week.
3. No. of tasks that are due over one week but under four week
4. No. of tasks that are due more than four weeks
5. No. of tasks that are not Due.

I tried using Group By condition as follows.

```
select (select count(TASK_ID) from rev$ta_task where (task_due_date >sysdate)) as notDue,
(select count(TASK_ID) from task where (task_due_date <sysdate)) as DuedMoreThan4Week,
(select count(TASK_ID) from task  where (task_due_date +7<sysdate)) as DuedOneWeek,
(select count(TASK_ID) from task  where (task_due_date +7<sysdate) and (task_due_date +30<sysdate)) as DuedFourWeek,
(select count(TASK_ID) from task  where (task_due_date is null)) as noDueDate
 from dual
```

and i am getting output from it as

```
NOTDUE  DUEDMORETHAN4WEEK   DUEDONEWEEK DUEDFOURWEEK    NODUEDATE
 4            4                 2            0             2
```

But to plot a chart from it we need all above values in single column instead of multiple columns, So how can i achieve it? Is there any better solution for it? as I am new to PLSQL I tried my best to write better Query.

> Note : I am using oracle 11g and Will use above query to plot chart in
>   Oracle-Apex.

Comment: I'm not seeing any PL/SQL in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to make a `UNION ALL` to make it.

```
select 'NOTDUE' name,count(TASK_ID) cnt from task where (task_due_date >sysdate) 
 UNION ALL
 select 'DUEDMORETHAN4WEEK',count(TASK_ID) from task where (task_due_date <sysdate)
 UNION ALL
 select 'DUEDONEWEEK',count(TASK_ID) from task where (task_due_date +7<sysdate)
 UNION ALL  
 select 'DUEDFOURWEEK',count(TASK_ID) from task where (task_due_date +7<sysdate) and (task_due_date +30<sysdate)
 UNION ALL
 select 'NODUEDATE',count(TASK_ID) from task where (task_due_date is null)
```

Comment: Hi @D-Shih , Thank you for response, from your Query i am getting 5 different columns , But i want all data in single column so that i can plot a chart based on it. Is it possible?

Comment: Hi @D-Shih , Thank you very much, The Union query resolved my problem, Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Ekaz No problem glad to help